# Вопрос по написанию футера сайта HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

Я - начинающий верстальщик. Прошёл парочку курсов. И при тренировке написания сайта появился один вопрос, на который никак не могу найти ответ.

В общем, не могу написать футер сайта, расположить элементы так, как это требуется, прилагаю фотографию. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует именно правая часть, не могу расположить элементы в правильном порядке. Пытался использовать FLEXBOX и GRID, но они вставлялись у меня в неправильном порядке, либо же все смещалось туда, куда мне не нужно)

Попрошу написать так, как сделали бы это вы, чтобы я разобрал ваш код и понял для себя, как это сделать. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: Разметку футера приложите в вопрос.

Comment: Хм... а зачем тут грид? Это три обычных блока внутри flex. Внутри которых можно свободно располагать div в виде отдельных строчек, без каких-то дополнительных стилей (ну `margin: 2em 0;` добавить строчкам, или около того)

Comment: в этом макете самое сложное это кастомный select - всё остальное ерунда

Answer (score 0):

можешь через bootstrap/tailwind с помощью col, либо сделать как отдельные объекты.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я написал кастомный select option - работает выбор по [клику](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) а выпадает по [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) в котором просто вставил внутрь блока .output методом [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) то что попадает в [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

А потом уже обычный [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Всю разметку и реализацию видно в примере =>

```js
let iconSelect = `<svg viewBox="-10 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M-9,1 0,8 9,1" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5" />
</svg>`;

let iconTwitter = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">

<path d="M512,97.248c-19.04,8.352-39.328,13.888-60.48,16.576c21.76-12.992,38.368-33.408,46.176-58.016
            c-20.288,12.096-42.688,20.64-66.56,25.408C411.872,60.704,384.416,48,354.464,48c-58.112,0-104.896,47.168-104.896,104.992
            c0,8.32,0.704,16.32,2.432,23.936c-87.264-4.256-164.48-46.08-216.352-109.792c-9.056,15.712-14.368,33.696-14.368,53.056
            c0,36.352,18.72,68.576,46.624,87.232c-16.864-0.32-33.408-5.216-47.424-12.928c0,0.32,0,0.736,0,1.152
            c0,51.008,36.384,93.376,84.096,103.136c-8.544,2.336-17.856,3.456-27.52,3.456c-6.72,0-13.504-0.384-19.872-1.792
            c13.6,41.568,52.192,72.128,98.08,73.12c-35.712,27.936-81.056,44.768-130.144,44.768c-8.608,0-16.864-0.384-25.12-1.44
            C46.496,446.88,101.6,464,161.024,464c193.152,0,298.752-160,298.752-298.688c0-4.64-0.16-9.12-0.384-13.568
            C480.224,136.96,497.728,118.496,512,97.248z" stroke-width="15px"/>
</svg>`;

let iconFacebook = `<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60.734 60.733"><path d="M57.378,0.001H3.352C1.502,0.001,0,1.5,0,3.353v54.026c0,1.853,1.502,3.354,3.352,3.354h29.086V37.214h-7.914v-9.167h7.914
        v-6.76c0-7.843,4.789-12.116,11.787-12.116c3.355,0,6.232,0.251,7.071,0.36v8.198l-4.854,0.002c-3.805,0-4.539,1.809-4.539,4.462
        v5.851h9.078l-1.187,9.166h-7.892v23.52h15.475c1.852,0,3.355-1.503,3.355-3.351V3.351C60.731,1.5,59.23,0.001,57.378,0.001z" stroke-width="3px"/></svg>`;

let iconHz = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="90" height="90" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="30" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>`;

document.querySelector(".user-icon").innerHTML = iconSelect;

document.querySelector(".facebook").innerHTML = iconFacebook;
document.querySelector(".twitter").innerHTML = iconTwitter;
document.querySelector(".hz").innerHTML = iconHz;

let output = document.querySelector(".output");

document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener("click", Selection);

function Selection(e) {
  e = event.target;
  if (e.classList.contains === "choice") return false;
  output.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

.select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.choice,
.option {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.choice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.option {
  user-select: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease 0.1s;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.select:hover .option {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  color: #000;
}

.user-icon {
  width: 20px;
}

.dashboard {
  background: #262626;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p span {
  color: #2ec927;
}

.icons {
  width: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons svg {
  max-width: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="choice">
        <div class="output">Выбрать язык</div>
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="option">Русский</div>
      <div class="option">English</div>
      <div class="option">Deutsch</div>
    </div>
    <!-- select -->

    <p><span>&#35;</span>UberEats</p>

    <div class="icons">
      <div class="facebook"></div>
      <div class="twitter"></div>
      <div class="hz"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <p>Об UberEats</p>
    <p>Станьте партнёром по доставке</p>
    <p>Станьте партнёром-рестораном</p>
  </div>
  <!-- item -->
  <div class="item">
    <p>Все города</p>
    <p>Цены</p>
    <p>Помощь</p>
    <p>FAQs</p>
  </div>
  <!-- item -->

</div>
```

Нажмите на `показать код` и `выполнить код`

иконки я вставил в javascript для того что бы не захломлять разметку но вы можете взять весь [html](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics) из [панели разработчика](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Разумеется что все [параграфы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) должны быть заменены на тег [ссылки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/A)